# Cannot set HorizontalAlignment for a specific cell

Tags: java, excel, alignment, katalon-studio

I have an Excel file and need to update 3 cell with different HorizontalAlignment => I tried the following way but I don't know the reason why all cells are applied the same style of HorizontalAlignment => I expect cell with header as "Status" is Center and the others are Left => Could you tell me what I should do?

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(file_path))
        Workbook expectedData = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream)
        Sheet sheet = expectedData.getSheet(sheet_name)
        Row row = sheet.getRow(rowN)
        Row row0 = sheet.getRow(0)

        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator()
        int i = 0

        while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

            Cell cell = cellIterator.next()
            CellStyle cs = cell.cellStyle
            cs.setWrapText(true)
            cs.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER)
            cs.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT)

            int cellIndex = cell.getColumnIndex()
            Cell cellResult = row0.getCell(cellIndex);   
            String valcellResult = cellResult.getStringCellValue()
            
            if(cellIndex >= startCol && cellIndex <= endCol &&valueArr[i]!=null) {
                if(valcellResult=="Status") {
                    cs.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)
                }
                cell.setCellValue(valueArr[i])
                cell.setCellStyle(cs)
                i++
            } else if(cellIndex > endCol) break
        }
```